# Cross-browser CSS for printing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I thought this would be easier.

A web app I am implementing must print some pages on a4 paper. These pages are prepared just for being printed (they are not the same displayed in the 'app'), so I do not need to include in the same CSS different formats for various media types (they are different from the other pages, monochromatic, etc.): I just need to write one CSS style for the prints.

The basic CSS I am using is Bootstrap V3, from which I removed all the rules for the media type 'print'. I use a second CSS for overwriting some Bootstrap rules and no other files.

The problem is this one:

- on the screen I see exactly the same page in Chrome and Safari;
- the printed results are completely different, especially for what concerns font size: Safari uses much smaller fonts.

Could you please suggest me a way to have the two browsers print the file in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Most debuggers allow you to debug in a specific media type. So for printing you can set the debugger to use `CSS media = print` to easily manipulate the styles as desired

I've had similar issues in the past with some `dt` tables and I resolved it by adding an extra layer of css resets to my `print` stylesheet.

Anyway it sounds like you just need to explicitly define the font and font-size in your print css.

```
@media print {
    html, body {
       font: Arial;
       font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

Its hard for me to suggest anything else without your tangibles but this is where I would start.

[image]

Comment: I am already using the dev emulation in 'media=print' mode. The problems are also in the page margins: Chrome uses much larger margins than Safari. Larger margins + large fonts destroy the layout I see on the screen.

Comment: For example, the same page is printed on 1 sheet of paper in Safari, 2 sheets (with the 2nd one empty) on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome and Safari for testing, you must check if you are using same printing engine for preview, because Chrome have built-in print enginge and to avoid that use CTRL+SHIFT+P shortcut. I had a lot of errors with Chrome built-in print engine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would rather try and find a solution which allows the users to select the engine they prefer (some users are not even able to press three keys at the same time).

Comment: There will never be the same output on different print engines. Here are some things why:
1) default margins are different
2) default headers and footers are different
3) default paper size is different
etc. That's why you should at least try to check the output correct on the same printer from different browsers, not on different printers on different browsers.

Comment: I am using the same printer and I am trying to set all of the margins&co. I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Using a font-size in points for print will likely yield a more uniform result. Pixels are for screens. Points are a print unit of measure...font-size: 12pt;